# Prevent duplicate mobile number in asp:CreateUserWizard

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, createuserwizard

How can I check for a duplicate mobile number before user get created?
something like Email Duplication Prevention by itself.
I need an event that runs after clicking "create user" button and before the user got created.

Comment: make unique value to mobile number in the database table

Comment: and would it prevents from creating user?
No need to manage error and warn user about what caused the error?!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CreatingUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard.creatinguser(v=vs.110).aspx) event. This event occurs before creating user on database, and contains [LoginCancelEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.logincanceleventargs.cancel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in its parameter.

In event code, check the entered mobile number exist or not and set the `Cancel` property to true or false.